# How to change date using mouse scroll in JSpinner?

Tags: java, jspinner

I have this code below; what I want is, how can I change date using mouse? Hoping someone can help.

```
    JSpinner dateStart = new JSpinner();    
    Date dateNow = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();    
    dateStart.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {
        public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {

            int direction = e.getWheelRotation();
            if (direction > 0 && dateStart.getPreviousValue() != null){ // down
                dateStart.setValue(dateStart.getPreviousValue());
            } else if (direction < 0 && dateStart.getNextValue() != null){ // up
                dateStart.setValue(dateStart.getNextValue());
            }               
        }
    });
    dateStart.setModel(new SpinnerDateModel(dateNow, null, null, Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH));
    dateStart.setBounds(560, 12, 138, 35);
    frmHistoryRequest.getContentPane().add(dateStart);
```

My code won't work, and I'm still new to Java programming.

Answer (score 0):

I hasn't extrasensory skills, what exactly doesn't work? Please provide precise log next time. Seems like dateStart should get full model in constructor to make full sequence of dates values in JSpinner, try to change nulls in

```
dateStart.setModel(new SpinnerDateModel(dateNow, null, null, Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH));
```

to real values. Hope it will help.